# Fingerprint Device Disconnected (04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint)

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on ASUS Zenbook. When I try to enroll a fingerprint, it says "Fingerprint device disconnected".

```bash
$ sudo lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:56ef IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I install a Fingerprint driver?

Comment: That particular fingerprint reader [is often detected, but never works for any Linux distribution](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:04f3-0c6e). Asus does not support Linux very often and their notebooks are almost 100% geared towards Windows. Hopefully someone can reverse-engineer the necessary commands needed to make that device work in the future 

Comment: This fingerprint scanner works for me in Debian Bookworm after installing latest `libfprint` from Debian git: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/libfprint/-/tree/debian/ possible this solution also applicable for Ubuntu.